# Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSLHandshakeFailed

Tags: python, mongodb, postman, eve

I am trying to create simple python eve app with following code:

But i am getting the following error in postman:

Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://127.0.0.1:27017/people.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly`enter code here`
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General

and in the mongodb server, got the error as :
     2018-08-11T00:36:36.565+0530 I NETWORK  [conn3] Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSLHandshakeFailed. Ending connection from 127.0.0.1:60241 (connection id: 3)

```
Is there i am missing anything?
Can you please help in resolving this issue?
```

Regards,
Narendra

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: while posting the code, i am getting too long error. not able to post the code